# Does my laptop connect to a server via its motherboard wifi or via my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm thinking about building a server, but I'm stuck on the motherboard.

I'm going to stream videos, etc to my laptop.
Does my laptop connect to the server through the motherboard wifi? or does it connect to router and then it is transfered to the server?
Do I need wifi on my server motherboard?

Comment: That is all depends if you want other devices to connect to the server. It is always the best option to just connect the server via network cable to the router and than any devices that can connect to the router ether WiFi or cable can access the server.

Answer (score 3):

> Does my laptop connect to the server through the motherboard wifi? or does it connect to router and then it is transfered to the server?

Your laptop will connect through its wireless adapter through WiFi to the router, and from there through WiFi to the wireless adapter of the server.

(Technically, you *could* connect the laptop directly to the server either with a wired or wireless connection, but that is rarely ideal and a router makes it easier to set up and also allows for more connections.)

> Do I need wifi on my server motherboard?

Only if you want it to connect wirelessly to the router. A wired connection from the server to the router is just fine as well; it has no bearing on the laptop’s connection.

All it really needs is an Ethernet adapter which most motherboards include. If you want it to connect to the router wirelessly, then you can get a wireless adapter card if the motherboard doesn’t have onboard WiFi.

Here is a typical server setup:

[image: Diagram of a server setup]